# minikube stops randomly and can't run kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Sometimes when Minikube is already running and I try to run any `kubectl` command (like `kubectl get pods`) I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.101:8443
```

So I stop Minikube and start it again and all `kubectl` commands work fine, but then after a while if I try to run any `kubectl` command I get the same error as above.

If I type `minikube ip` I get `192.168.99.100`. Why does `kubectl` try to connect to `192.168.99.101` (as mentioned in the error) when Minikube is running on `192.168.99.100`?

Note that I'm very new to Kubernetes.

`kubectl config get-contexts` gives me this output:

```
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         minikube   minikube   minikube
```

This is `minikube logs` output https://pastebin.com/kb5jNRyW

Comment: What's the `minikube version`?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas v0.28.2

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `kubectl config get-contexts` pls?

Comment: I found this error when I started minikube `Error restarting cluster:  restarting kube-proxy: waiting for kube-proxy to be up for configmap update: timed out waiting for the condition` is this normal or I should not have any error when running minikube ?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I updated it

Comment: Yeah, a `minikube logs` via Pastebin wouldn't hurt either …

Comment: Oh no, pls no, link to Pastebin ;)

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I did

Comment: Your control plane is hosed. Not sure if it's to few resources or something with the VM but I'd do a `minikube delete` and then a `minikube start` again. Report back if the issue persists, yes please?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas ok I will try it

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas after running Minikube I didn't get the error `Error restarting cluster: restarting kube-proxy: waiting for kube-proxy to be up for configmap update: timed out waiting for the condition` so I guess I don't have enough resources ??

Comment: You did or you did not get this error?? 8->

Comment: I didn't get the error :) the last message I get is `Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.`

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas If I stop Minikube then start it with 2GB of memory like this `minikube --memory 2048 start` wil it be enough ? and will it always use 2G each time I start it or I need to specify the memory every time ?

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when the IP of your VM might be changed, and your minikube is pointing to the previous IP, You can check through `minikube ip` and then check the IP of the VM created, they will be different.

You can also try `minikube status`, your output will be :

`minikube: Running
cluster: Stopped
kubectl: Misconfigured: pointing to stale minikube-vm.
To fix the kubectl context, run minikube update-context`

You can try `minikube update-context` and if it doesn't run even then, try `minikube start` followed by `minikube update-context`, it won't download everything again, it will only start the VM if shut down.

Comment: TIL about `minikube update-context`, thanks Ali! My `delete` method is prolly a tad to hardcore anyways ;)